# How do I check to see if a user Input matches an element of a 2D array? JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, match, element

I am creating a student grade book that allows a user to input their students names and 4 grades, then have options to calculate student and class averages, as shown in the pic below.

[image: Program UI]

With the code below, I am receiving the student average as "0.0%" and no errors. Am I correctly instructing the program to see if the students name matches the appropriate element in the two-dimensional array?

I have all the other parts of the program working.

```java
private String[][] grades = new String[16][5];

//Declare Variables
String firstName, lastName, name;
String test1, test2, test3, test4;

test1 = t1Input.getText();
test2 = t2Input.getText();
test3 = t3Input.getText();
test4 = t4Input.getText();

firstName = firstInput.getText();
lastName = lastInput.getText();
name = firstName + " " + lastName + ": ";

grades[students][0] = name;
grades[students][1] = test1;
grades[students][2] = test2;
grades[students][3] = test3;
grades[students][4] = test4;

students++;
```

```java
private void sAvgInputActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String firstName = firstInput.getText();
    String lastName = lastInput.getText();
    String name = firstName + " " + lastName + ": ";
    int sum = 0;
    double divide = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
        if (name.equals(grades[0][1])) {
            for (int grade = 1; grade <= 4; grade++) {
                sum = Integer.parseInt(grades[i][1]) + i;
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    divide = sum / 4;
    gradesOutput.setText(firstName + "'s grade average is " + divide + "%.");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the loop to this:

```java
//assume it as a simple table since its 2d array
//Since you are storing the name in first(0th index) column,
//only row should be loop
for (int i = 0; grades[i][0] != null; i++) {
    if (name.equals(grades[i][0])) {
        for (int grade = 1; grade <= 4; grade++)
            //same row,different column
            sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(grades[i][grade]);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thanks for the help -  I was a bit confused because it wasn't in our lesson content for school :)

Comment: Update @sittsering It's only finding the average of the first student I put in, any others are returned with "0.0%"

Comment: there was extra bracket, i removed it .